# bind multiple objects in play framework 2.0 from a form

Tags: forms, scala, binding, playframework-2.0

i am desperately trying to receive a list of values from a form submission and bind it to a list of objects.

What works is to retrieve a single row:

```
//class
case class Task(name: String, description: String)

val taskForm: Form[Task] = Form(
  mapping(
  "name" -> text,
  "description" -> text

  )(Task.apply)(Task.unapply)
)


//form
<tr>
  <td><input name="name" type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Name..."></td>
  <td><textarea name="description" class="autoexpand span7" rows="1"     placeholder="Description..."></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>

//receiving action:
val task = taskForm.bindFromRequest.get
```

But now i want to submit multiple objects of type task like this for instance:

```
<tr>
  <td><input name="name[0]" type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Name..."></td>
  <td><textarea name="description[0]" class="autoexpand span7" rows="1" placeholder="Description..."></textarea></td>                   
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="name[1]" type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Name..."></td>
  <td><textarea name="description[1]" class="autoexpand span7" rows="1" placeholder="Description..."></textarea></td>                   
</tr>
```

Doing a 
taskForm.bindFromRequest.get
now fails.

Did somebody come up with a solution to this? Or do you handle such a situation totally different?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, thanks for hinting me to look at the docs again, i've seen them already, but never could make up how to combine it to make it work. I think this is because i am a total scala noob.
However, i got it working after giving it some time again, this is my solution:

```
//classes
case class Task(name: String, description: String)
case class Tasks(tasks: List[Task])

val taskForm: Form[Tasks] = Form(
  mapping(
  "tasks" -> list(mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "description" -> text
  )(Task.apply)(Task.unapply))
)(Tasks.apply)(Tasks.unapply)
)

//form
<tr>
  <td><input name="tasks[0].name" type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Name..."></td>
  <td><textarea name="tasks[0].description" class="autoexpand span7" rows="1" placeholder="Description..."></textarea></td>                   
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="tasks[1].name" type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Name..."></td>
  <td><textarea name="tasks[1].description" class="autoexpand span7" rows="1" placeholder="Description..."></textarea></td>                   
</tr>
```

And finally do a:

```
val tasks = taskForm.bindFromRequest.get
```

to retrieve the list of tasks.

Comment: Wow you nailed it. For those out there that were having trouble the part that got me was wrapping `list()` around a sub-map

Comment: But how about binding a list of the same object type? (something like: case class Person(name: String, friends: List[Person]) ? )

Comment: This is great, but what about doing this from Java? The most rudimentary Java framework does this with ease. Shocked this is not there in Play.

Answer (score 2):

From the playframework documentation [page](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms):

> **Repeated values**
>
> A form mapping can also define repeated values:
>
> ```
> case class User(name: String, emails: List[String])
>
> val userForm = Form(
>   mapping(
>     "name" -> text,
>     "emails" -> list(text)
>   )(User.apply, User.unapply)
> )
> ```
>
> When you are using repeated data like this, the form values sent by
>   the browser must be named emails[0], emails[1], emails[2], etc.