# Handling fieldsets in Play! Framework 2.3 (Java)

Tags: java, forms, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to figure out how Play! handles forms where multiple fields with the same name are used.

For example, take a look at this form snippet:

```
<div class="controls" id="orderlines-container">
            <div class="orderline form-inline">

                <select class="form-control" name="productId[]">
                    <option disabled selected>Select product...</option>
                    @for(product<-Product.findAll()) {
                      <option value="@product.id">@product.name</option>
                    }
                </select>

                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="quantity[]" />

                <select class="form-control" name="price[]">
                      <option value="memberPrice" >Member price</option>
                      <option value="publicPrice" >Public price</option>
                </select>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-remove"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </span> </a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btn-add-create"> Add line...</a> 
    </div>
```

I'm using the bracket notation because the user can add as many orderlines as he would like by clicking the "Add line..." button. When clicking on the button, a JavaScript function clones the `<div class="orderline">` and appends it just below. So basically, the submitted form contains several orderlines.

Now what I want to do is to collect all of the data in my controller, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Some people suggested me to do something like this in the controller:

```
public static Result createOrder(String[] quantity, String[] productId, String[] price) {
     for(int i=0; i<quantity.length; i++){
         ...
     }
     for(int i=0; i<productId.length; i++){
         ...
     }
     for(int i=0; i<price.length; i++){
         ...
     }
}
```

But the problem with this is that it requires me to implement a custom implicit `QueryStringBindable` for the type `Array[String]`. Isn't that too much for such a basic feature?

So my question is **how can I handle a form with a variable number of parameters that have the same name?** Like, how would you implement a shopping cart where you create several orderlines(in a completely random order), and then submit them to create an order?

PS : I already tried to have different names (like [`productId0`, `quantity0`, `price0`] for the first line, then [`productId1`, `quantity1`, `price1`] and so on...) for each input, using JavaScript, but it ended up being too complex to keep the index accurate...

Comment: Answer to similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10223431/116509

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584282/2523628

The solution is to get the raw data using

```
Map<String,String[]> params = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
```

All the values are stored in a `Map` that looks like this:

```
userId
- 1
orderDate
- 2014-09-10T14:21
productId[]
- 21
- 61
quantity[]
- 1
- 2
price[]
- memberPrice
- memberPrice
status
- processed
```

And then just manually parse the values. It looks like the values are stored in the same order in each array, so i'ts still possible to know which ones match (this is just a guess).

Also, the bracket notation is useless. If removed, the data is still the same, in the same order.

I'm still wondering if there is any other solution, especially one using the automatic binding feature.

Comment: By the way, the question that I found isn't specifically about the `name="someName[]"` notation, and the answer for that question could've just been to set a `name` attribute on his inputs and then get the data by calling `String someData = Form.form().bindFromRequest().get("someName");`, which doesn't work for arrays.